# webgl relocating buffered data in graphics card memory?

Tags: webgl, webgl2

So I created a library to manager data buffered using webgl, it knows how to avoid memory segmentation on the graphics card by using a single only a single buffer, it knows how to find the tightest fitting portion of free memory to refill when new objects are added and knows how to, lets me tell it how large a buffer is expected to need to be, when necessary, how to copy a portion of memory to another place where there is more room as new values are added into the vector. 
So from the outside I can completely forget about garbage collection and i can call a function like append( to just add new values into an array), and another function to release the memory.
However
webgl currently does not support copyBufferSubData. webgl2 lets you do this. I know one obvious solution would be to keep the vector contents in the main memory as well as in the graphics card memory, but i wondered if anyone knows a less wasteful solution?

If not, I will just store the vectors in main memory when old webgl is used and do it differently for each type.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way in WebGL (and GLES 2.0 for that mater) to copy content of a buffer back to main memory or to another buffer. However you can propose an extension with such an ability.